# Using a decorator function defined as an instance variable

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

(Although this question is specifically about Flask, it can be generalised as per the title)

I'm trying to use Flask's `app.route()` decorator inside a class. However, the Flask app is initialised as an instance variable, i.e. `self.server` is set to the app. This means that I can't use the decorator, as `self` is undefined outside of the decorated method. I would like to be able to do the following:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Flask(__name__)

    @self.server.route('/')
    def home():
        return '<h1>Success</h1>'
```

Are there any work-arounds for this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the function in the context of the `__init__` method. Then, to make the function able to be called normally, set the `home` member equal to it.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Flask(__name__)

        # This is indented at __init__'s level, so a new instance of the function
        # is defined every time __init__ runs. That means a new instance
        # is defined for each instance of the class, and so it can be wrapped with
        # the instance's "self" value.
        @self.server.route('/')
        def home_func():
            return '<h1>Success</h1>'

        # Then, you make it an object member manually:
        self.home = home_func
```

Comment: I would contend that this is not a forward-looking solution, as you will eventually wind up with a massive `__init__()` method containing all of your route definitions and their respective functionality. Better to use the [`add_url_rule()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule), as explained in my own (and @rumdrums') answer to this question.

Comment: In the case of Flask, that's probably better. However, this is a great question even for people who aren't using Flask. Additionally, defining functions in this way takes only one more line per function than the `add_url_rule`, so I don't think that "a massive `__init__()` method" is particularly significant.

Comment: Fair enough! Purely as an academic exercise, one could also use the `route` decorator to monkey-patch methods on the `MyClass` class in the `__init__` method, by executing something like `self.home = self.server.route('/')(self.home)`. This is a handy way of decorating functions/methods in some of the trickier scenarios one can run into, not just Flask and routing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `route()` decorator, you should use the [`add_url_rule` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) of the `self.server` object, like so:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Flask(__name__)
        self.server.add_url_rule('/', 'home', self.home)
        self.server.add_url_rule('/route-1', 'route-1', self.route_1)
        self.server.add_url_rule('/route-2', 'route-2', self.route_2)

    def home():
        return '<h1>Success</h1>'

    def route_1():
        ...

    def route_2():
        ...
```

This pattern allows you to define your route handlers as methods on the class and is much easier to read, as you can see all of your URL rules in one block.

Comment: Where is the self parameter for each method? i.e., `home`, `route_1` and `route_2`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your overall use case is, but you may be better served by not embedding the app object in a class and instead using Flask's [Pluggable Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/) module. This would allow you to cleanly define your views as classes that inherit from flask.views.View. Example:

```
import flask
import flask.views

class MyClass(flask.views.View):
  def dispatch_request(self):
    return '<h1>Success</h1>'

app.add_url_rule('/test', view_func=MyClass.as_view('home'))
```

This is definitely more code given the small example, but this gives you more flexibility to define other classes or functions with their own routes, and potentially to consider MethodViews instead, which provide a good structure for defining multiple HTTP methods and associating them with a single class.